# Printing through a specified printer using JAVA AWT/ jnlp from web browser

Tags: java, printing, applet, awt, jnlp

I have a requirement to print documents via web browser directly to multiple printers depending on user choice. User will have different printer setup on our service and will select which to use.

This functionality is used by dropship.amazon.in (Warehouse Management System  from Amazon). They call it PackStations

Following are the steps to use packstation:

1. First we need to save printer name or address for different categories like label printing, bar-code printing.
2. Clicking on start in front of a specified category will download a jnlp file with the following source.

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

   <jnlp spec='1.0+' codebase= 'https://dropship.amazon.in:443/DropShipCentral/PrintServer/'>
   <information>
       <title>VendorFlex Print Server</title>
       <vendor>Amazon.com</vendor>
       <description>VendorFlex Print Server</description>
       <description kind="short">VendorFlexPrintServer</description>
       <icon href="AmazonVFPrintServer.jpg" kind="splash"/>
   </information>

   <security>
       <all-permissions/>
   </security>

   <resources>
       <j2se version="1.6+"/>
       <jar href="vendorflex-printserver.jar" main="true"/>
       <jar href="apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar"/>
       <jar href="apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar"/>
       <jar href="jakartacommons-codec.jar"/>
       <jar href="jakartacommons-lang.jar"/>
       <jar href="jakartacommons-logging-adapters.jar"/>
       <jar href="jakartacommons-logging-api.jar"/>
       <jar href="apache-commons-io.jar"/>
       <jar href="json-org-java.jar"/>
       <jar href="vfprintservershared.jar"/>
   </resources>

   <application-desc main-class="amazon.internal.dropship.printserver.main.PSMain">
           <argument>QNAY</argument>
   <argument>test</argument>
   <argument>https://dropship.amazon.in:443</argument>

   </application-desc>
   ```
3. Executing this file will show two button, start and stop.
4. After starting if i print a bar-code from web browser, it will print through a specified printer without any prompt.

Now i have following doubts

1. How the browser is communication with AWT app ? does the print command is directly sent to AWT app ?
2. Is the print command from browser is first sent to amazon server then it gives command to AWT app to print. If this is the case how the server matches the user of web browser and user of AWT app are same.

If there is any documentation where i can get a head-start on this, it would be really helpful.

Thanks